# Refactoring - remove call to method

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

What I want is refactor this:

`method(getString(R.string.message));` -> `method(R.string.message);`

Or how to say for non-android people...

`method(getString(1234));` -> `method(1234);`

Which refactor tool in IntellJ (Android Studio) can remove call to one method but preserve argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make `getString` do nothing but return its argument (temporarily).
2. Inline the method at all call sites.
3. Restore the original `getString`.

Comment: Thanks, that works... Although it's still little uncomfortable... but it's the best solution yet... thanks